# Bootstrap 3: How to drop the left sidebar drop below content using push-pull

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and on mobile devices I'd like to vertically stack all the div's (sidebar & content) and position the left sidebar below the main container (currently to the right of the left sidebar) on mobile (xs) devices. The HTML, looks like this

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-push-9"> Sidebar</div>
   <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-pull-3"> Main Container</div>
 </div>
```

The problem with above is that, using `col-xs-push-9` on sidebar and `col-xs-pull-3` on main container they appear in reverse order on large(`lg`) medium(`md`) and (`sm`) devices. I do not want to reverse the order but only want to have the left sidebar below the main container on extra small mobile devices.

I want a bootstrap solution not a JS / jQuery solution.

Pls help.

Regards,
dk

Comment: If you want them to stack on `xs` devices you should remove the `col-xs-*` since the default behavior is to stack vertically on xs screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think "mobile-first", layout the columns in the desired mobile order first, then use push/pull to adjust the columns for larger screens..

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3"> Main Container</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9"> Sidebar</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/8g4UL0J43K

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap inherits properties for larger grids from the properties set for smaller grids. Therefore you have to set the pull and push to 0 for grids larger than xs, sm, like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-push-9 col-sm-push-0"> Sidebar</div>
   <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-pull-3 col-sm-pull-0"> Main Container</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This idea is good, make you think more uses of BS default classes like `col-sm-push-0` However in your code we need to also add `col-xs-3` and 'col-xs-9` to resp. div's. Without those the div's aren't floats and Sidebar will stack on top of Main

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 you use ".order-*-{n}"

This example has 3 columns.  On a large view they are evenly spaced and in the same order as the HTML.  On a medium view, HTML columns 1 and 3 are half width and across from each other while the middle HTML column is dropped to the bottom and full width.  On small views they are each full width in HTML column order 1,3,2.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 order-1"></div>
        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 order-sm-last order-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 order-3"></div>
</div>
```